# recursion in c stacks

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion

here is the code to partition in merge sort..am not able to understand actually how does recusrion works in it!!

MERGE SORT PARTITION

```
void partition(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int mid;
    if(low < high){
         mid = (low + high)/2;
         partition(arr, low, mid);
         partition(arr, mid + 1, high);
         mergeSort(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}
```

actually am getting messed up in many recursive problems and am not able to understand how does system stack works in recursion...
am a beginner..

Comment: Your method signature is indicative of [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). I believe you have confused [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). They are distinctly different!

Comment: From this piece of code, it is difficult to judge what the problem is. Post the relevant code and clarify what is not happening that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take an example of

Array `arr ={ 5,2,4,7,1,3,2,6};` 8 elements

```
                            1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                                  ^(partition+mergeSort)
                                  |  
                    +------------+ +---------------+
                    |                              |
                2 4 5 7                          1 2 3 6
                    ^   (partition+mergeSort)        ^ (partition+mergeSort)  
                    |                              |
                +--+ +---+                     +--+ +---+
                |        |                     |        |
               2  5     4  7                 1   3     2  6
                     ^ (partition+mergeSort)          ^  (partition+mergeSort) 
                     |                              | 
                +---+ +---+                    +---+ +---+
                |         |                    |         |
              5   2     4   7                1  3      2   6 
                 4 elements                      4 elements 

                          Initial Unsorted Array
```

Go from bottom to top, two arrays are formed with

`arr[low...mid]` and
`arr[mid+1...high]` on each recursive calls, and finally they both get merged.

Partitioning & Merging process continues as long as `low` < `high`

Its just an example how `mergeSort` is working here, you can follow the code with this example.

A call with `partition(arr, 0,7)` on this unsorted array will have :

On first pass `mid =3` 
 `arr` gets divided into 2 parts using

`partion(arr,0,3)` and `partion(arr,4,7)`

Each of those partitions are again spitted up into two parts i.e for 0 to 3 gets divided into `(0,1)` & `(2,3)` , further again `(0,1)` and `(1,1)` . `(1,1)` is skipped as `low > high` this last 2 elements are merged up  with `mergeSort`

A group of such small sorted array are then finally merged up as it comes out of recursion on subsequent passes.

This is bit difficult to explain here, in textual format, try it on paper,I'm sure you can figure it out, with even more smaller array, say for 4 elements.

Comment: can u please illustrate how is recursion actually working in it

Comment: thanx,can u please tell what parameters are being passes to mergeSort(arr, low, mid, high); every time and how

Comment: thanx,can u please tell what parameters are being passes to mergeSort(arr, low, mid, high); every time and how

Comment: @ayushnigam updated, but please try it on paper, its bit difficult to explain here. fyi..`mid=3` b'coz of implicit typecast

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to make recursive functions simpler for you. Take for example a small example of factorial pseudo-code:

```
int fact(n)
{
  if(n==1 || n==0) return 1;
  else
  return (n*fact(n-1));
}
```

What this will do is create a stack of functions. Suppose I call `fact(3)` this will make a stack like:

```
fact(0)
fact(1)
fact(2)
fact(3)
```

where each function is pushed into the stack. First `fact(3)` is called. `fact(3)` calls `fact(2)`. So after the passes --

Stack build up:

```
                                               fact(0)
                                   fact(1)     fact(1)
                       fact(2)     fact(2)     fact(2)
empty --> fact(3) ---> fact(3) --> fact(3) --> fact(3)
```

Now the function catches `n=0` and returns `1`. Now the functions start popping out.

Stack :

```
   fact(0) -----> (returns 1) = 1
                    fact(1) -----> (returns 1) * 1 (1's popped out)
                                     fact(2) -----> (returns 2) * 1 (1 is actually 1*1)
                                                      fact(3) -----> (returns 3) * (2 = 2*1*1)
                                                                                          ----->6
```

**EDIT:Added pop functionally. As for the sorting stack kindly check out @P0W's answer.**

Trying taking a small example and build your stack. Then move onto complex ones. Remember practice is the key. This is how recursive functions work as a stack.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: can u please explain bit more about pop part and explain in the same way for merge sort partition

Comment: This is now my go-to answer for explaining recursion while calculating a factorial. Awesome answer!