# Factorial using recursion in C

Tags: recursion, factorial

We all know the program for this

```
int fact(int n)
{
  if(n==0)  
    return(1);

  return(n*fact(n-1));
}
```

But what is not clear to me is how the inner thing is happening?

How is it calculating `5*4*3*2*1`  (if n is 5)

Please give a clear explanation on this.

Thanks.....

Comment: Check my answer on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420574/recursion-in-c-stacks/18420787#18420787

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger? You'll see it.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, the recursive definition of factorial can be expressed recursively like so (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)):

[image: recursive factorial definition]

Consider how this works for `n = 3`, using `==` to mean equivalence:

`3! == 2! * 3 == (1! * 2) * 3 == ((1) * 2) * 3`

This can be derived purely symbolically by repeatedly applying the recursive rule.

What this definition does is first expand out a given factorial into an equivalent series of multiplications.  It then performs the actual multiplications.  The C code you have performs the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

What might help to understand it, is that when you are recursively calling the function, **the new "cycle" will use N-1, not N.**
This way, once you get to N==0, the last function you called will return a 1. At this point all the stack of functions are waiting for the return of the nested function. That is how now **you exactly multiply the results of each of the functions on the stack.**
In other words, you factorize the number given as input.