# where are the values being stored in this factorial calculator that only has one var?

Tags: recursion, storage, factorial

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorialFinder(int x){

    if(x==1)(
      return 1;
    }else{
      return x*factorialFinder(x-1);
    }

}

int main(){

    cout << factorialFinder(5) << endl;

}
```

when it cycles through and says x-1  which is 4 times x which is 5 you get 20, so we have this number 20. Where is 20 stored. does it become x? if so what happens to 4 which is needed to go  to three the next cycle.... im really confused about how these numbers are being stored, passed around, and where exactly are they returning to?

Comment: It is called "the stack". As the function keeps being called recursively, the program is keeping track of "how deep it is", and "where to go after it is finished". It also includes "what value did I call it with". It keeps all the information on the stack. Important concept.

Comment: thank you soooo much, i was so confused as to how these numbers just float around and keep re applying itself.

Comment: Study scope and lifetime, and particularly study how stacks work.  Local variables are usually allocated on a "stack", which is like a fresh piece of paper added to a pile every time a subroutine is called.  When the subroutine exits, the last sheet of paper is sent to the garbage can and it uses the former value for local variables.  When you have "factorialFinder(x-1)" called with a value of 4, a new sheet of paper is put on the stack and told "factorialFinder has a value of X of 3, which then adds another one saying "X has a value of 2".

Comment: Reasonable primer can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack . Any computer science text will go into much more detail. Robert's comment is pretty helpful as a quick introduction, too... Definitely a concept worth understanding.

Comment: thanks robert! will the x thats equal to 20 after the first cycle do the same thing?

Comment: X will never be 20.  If called with a value of 5, the stack won't get "popped" back to the level of the first function until 4! is calculated, which will give a result of 24.  It will then take 5*24 to get 5!, or 120.  I'll point out that on each new sheet of paper analogy, that information is written at the top about what is was doing before being interrupted with a new subroutine and how to continue.  When new sheets of paper are created, that's called "pushing".  When pieces of paper are put in the trash, that's called "popping".

Comment: possible duplicate of [recursion in c stacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420574/recursion-in-c-stacks)